# How to produce the ganzfeld effect?

Tags: hearing, eye-movement

This is the closest stack exchange site I could find that suites my question: How can I best produce the ganzfeld effect? I tried with noise canceling earbuds, white noise, and a paper sleep mask.
I've composed some questions below:
Can I move my eyes?
Can I move my body?
Can I make any noise?
How long will it take for effects to begin?
Any other information will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!